# How to reset font back to original when button is clicked in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click

    txtRate.Text = "0"
    lblPromotional.ForeColor = Color.Empty
    lblPromotional.BackColor = Color.Empty
    lblPromotional.Font = originalfontname()
```

It's not working for font?

Comment: What does `originalfontname()` do?

Comment: i dont know about that...Im using it as an random

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use originalFont, then you can just manually change the label font by

```
lblPromotional.Font = New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 16, FontStyle.Bold)
```

or whatever font you used. Here is the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache the entire `Font` object before you change it - not just the font name.

```
Class SomeForm Inherits Form

    Private originalFont As Font

    Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.originalFont = Me.lblPromotional.Font
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click

        txtRate.Text = "0"
        lblPromotional.ForeColor = Color.Empty
        lblPromotional.BackColor = Color.Empty
        lblPromotional.Font = Me.originalFont
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Mr. Dai can u let me any other code same as used in backcolor and fontcolor...I dont wanna make a sub routine...Please